# Convert Multiple List Of Strings to different objects in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I have multiple list of strings in my request array. I have to iterate each list and take its first elements and form an object as bucketList similarly second elements of each list and form another object. How can be this achieved in jolt?

Request Packet:

```json
{
  "recordSet": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "bucketIdArray": [ "M03", "M02" ],
      "bucketNameArray": [ "EmployeeBucket200", "EmployeeBucket100" ],
      "bucketUsageArray": [ "500000000", "5000" ],
      "postBucketValueArray": [ "5004000", "5000" ]
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "bucketIdArray": [ "M04" ],
      "bucketNameArray": [ "EmployeeBucket300" ],
      "bucketUsageArray": [ "500000000" ],
      "postBucketValueArray": [ "5004000" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Response Expected:

```json
{
  "datas": {
    "historyDetails": [
      {
        "historyId": "123",
        "bucketlist": [
          {
            "bucketId": "M03",
            "bucketName": "EmployeeBucket200",
            "bucketUsage": "500000000",
            "postBucketValue": "5004000"
          },
          {
            "bucketId": "M02",
            "bucketName": "EmployeeBucket300",
            "bucketUsage": "50000",
            "postBucketValue": "5004000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "historyId": "456",
        "bucketlist": [
          {
            "bucketId": "M04",
            "bucketName": "EmployeeBucket300",
            "bucketUsage": "500000000",
            "postBucketValue": "5004000"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this **shift** spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "id": "datas.historyDetails[&1].&",
          "*": { "*": "datas.historyDetails[&2].bucketlist[&].&1" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

If the `Array` strings needed to be removed from the key names, then each key-value pair should explicitly be specified for them such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "datas.historyDetails[&1].&",
          "bucketIdArray": { "*": "datas.historyDetails[&2].bucketlist[&].bucketId" },
          "bucketNameArray": { "*": "datas.historyDetails[&2].bucketlist[&].bucketName" },
          "bucketUsageArray": { "*": "datas.historyDetails[&2].bucketlist[&].bucketUsage" },
          "postBucketValueArray": { "*": "datas.historyDetails[&2].bucketlist[&].postBucketValue" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Another option would be adding three more steps before our original **shift** spec in order to prevent hardcoding of each keys individually with `Array` suffix such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&2.&.key",
            "@": "&2.&.val"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "key": "=split('Array',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "val": "&.[&2].@(1,key[0])"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "id": "datas.historyDetails[&1].&",
          "*": { "*": "datas.historyDetails[&2].bucketlist[&].&1" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]